# python multiprocessing pool Assertion Error in interpreter

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a sample program to test the usage of multiprocessing pool of workers in python 2.7.2+

This is the code i have written in the python ubuntu interpreter

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> def name_append(first_name,last_name):
...     return first_name+" "+last_name
...

>>> from functools import partial
>>> partial_name_append=partial(name_append,'kiran')
>>> partial_name_append('acb')
'kiran acb'
>>> abc='kiran'

>>> pool=Pool(processes=4)
>>> pool.map(partial_name_append,abc)
['kiran k', 'kiran i', 'kiran r', 'kiran a', 'kiran n']
>>> pool.close()
>>> pool.join()

>>> pool.map(partial_name_append,abc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 226, in map
    assert self._state == RUN
AssertionError
```

After i got pickle errors, over my pool of workers code for large data sets, i am trying to do small examples and try to figure out what is the error.

I dont understand why the same statement 'pool.map' doesn't work, when it has worked above. I think i have executed the 'pool map' correctly but i dont understand the reason.

Is this error related to "PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.function failed"

Can someone help me out ?

Thanks

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool()` doesn't work in the interactive interpreter. Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: `multiprocess.Pool()` however does work in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You typed:

```
>>> pool.close()
```

[from the docs:](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close)

> close()
>
> Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the tasks 
>   have been completed the worker processes will exit.

Of course you can't use the pool anymore, you closed it.

Comment: so if i use 'pool=Pool(processes=4)' again then i can use it again right ? Edit: It worked when i assigned the pool again ..Thank you .. If you don't mind i have another question "PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup builtin.function failed"
I am not able to figure out why i keep getting this error when i use pool.map() in a program

Comment: don't close the pool at all (until you don't need it anymore).  you don't need to `join()` the pool (and therefore don't need to close it either) to wait for results from `Pool.map()`, it already blocks until the results are ready.  you can just keep using `map()` all you like.