# AssertionError using pathos.multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pathos

I'm using python 2.7. Here's some of my code:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

class pair_scraper(object):

    #code and various methods ...

    def parallelized_processing(self):
    '''
    Parallelize length extraction of
    relevant files.
    '''
    pool = Pool(self.pool_size)
    pool.map(self.length_processer, self.zip_files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

However when I run this, I get a blank `AssertionError`:

```
/...file.py in parallelized_processing(self)
     69         '''
     70         pool = Pool(self.pool_size)
---> 71         pool.map(self.length_processer, self.zip_files)
     72         # pool.close()
     73         # pool.join()

/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.pyc in map(self, f, *args, **kwds)
    134         AbstractWorkerPool._AbstractWorkerPool__map(self, f, *args, **kwds)
    135         _pool = self._serve()
--> 136         return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
    137     map.__doc__ = AbstractWorkerPool.map.__doc__
    138     def imap(self, f, *args, **kwds):

/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    248         Equivalent of `map()` builtin
    249         '''
--> 250         assert self._state == RUN
    251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 

AssertionError:
```

This error seems to resemble the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368810/python-multiprocessing-pool-assertion-error-in-interpreter), although the fix there was more obvious. I ran the above code removing `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` but got the same results.

Thoughts?

Comment: `pathos` is built to mitigate some of the overhead in creating a `Pool`, especially if you are going to be repeatedly creating a similarly configured `ProcessingPool`.  `pathos` will cache a `Pool`, and reuse it instead of create a new one if the construction arguments are the same.  So, if it's closed, it will be closed when you try to use `map`.  In `pathos`, a `Pool` object also has `clear` and `restart` methods, which are used for clearing the pool cache, and for "reopening" a closed pool. I'd suggest also separating the `map` call from the creation and "destruction" of the pool.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcKerns. Is there a particular way you would recommend "separating" the commands?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.  `pathos` as you have coded originally, will use one shared `Pool` across all instances of the class.  Using `clear`, you can make sure there are different instances of the `Pool`.  It depends on what your use case is.